# Сгруппировать массив - C++

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм

Всем привет,есть такое задание . Оно у меня проходит 0% . Я уверен ,что я решил её верно .
Помогите пожалуйста!

Вот задача

Дано массив из N целых положительных чисел. Требуется сгруппировать элементы массива следующим способом: в начале должны идти числа, кратные 2, затем из оставшихся, кратные 3, затем из оставшихся, кратные 5, затем кратные 7, затем кратные 11, и затем все остальные числа с сохранением их порядка следования относительно друг друга.

Формат входных данных

В первой строке задано одно число N (1 <= N <= 10000). В следующей строке задано N целых чисел, разделенных одним пробелом, – элементы массива. Элементы массива не превосходят 1000.

Формат выходных данных

Выведите N чисел, разделенных одним пробелом – измененный массив.

Пример входных данных

```
15
9 55 13 4 6 25 7 14 7 21 33 4 12 5 10
```

Пример выходных данных

```
4 6 14 4 12 10 9 21 33 55 25 5 7 7 13
```

```cpp
vector<int>massiv;
vector<int>poradok;
int n, cis;
cin >> n;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cin >> cis;
    massiv.pb(cis);
}

for (int i = 0; i < massiv.size(); i++)
{
    if (massiv[i] % 2 == 0)
    {
        poradok.pb(massiv[i]);
        massiv.erase(massiv.begin() + i);
    }
    else if (massiv[i + 1] % 2 == 0)
    {
        poradok.pb(massiv[i + 1]);
        massiv.erase(massiv.begin() + (i + 1));
    }
}




for (int i = 0; i < massiv.size(); i++)
{
    if (massiv[i] % 3 == 0)
    {
        poradok.pb(massiv[i]);
        massiv.erase(massiv.begin() + i);
    }
    else if (massiv[i + 1] % 3 == 0)
    {
        poradok.pb(massiv[i + 1]);
        massiv.erase(massiv.begin() + (i + 1));
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < massiv.size(); i++)
{
    if (massiv[i] % 5 == 0)
    {
        poradok.pb(massiv[i]);
        massiv.erase(massiv.begin() + i);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < massiv.size(); i++)
{
    if (massiv[i] % 7 == 0)
    {
        poradok.pb(massiv[i]);
        massiv.erase(massiv.begin() + i);
    }
    else if (massiv[i + 1] % 7 == 0)
    {
        poradok.pb(massiv[i + 1]);
        massiv.erase(massiv.begin() + (i + 1));
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < massiv.size(); i++)
{
    if (massiv[i] % 11 == 0)
    {
        poradok.pb(massiv[i]);
        massiv.erase(massiv.begin() + i);
    }
    else if (massiv[i + 1] % 11 == 0)
    {
        poradok.pb(massiv[i + 1]);
        massiv.erase(massiv.begin() + (i + 1));
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < massiv.size(); i++)
{
    poradok.pb(massiv[i]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < poradok.size(); i++)
{
    cout << poradok[i] << " ";
}

cout << endl;
```

Comment: Пример, к сожалению, не показателен, ибо не отражает требования сохранить относительный порядок чисел с делителем больше `11`.  Такое число там только одно - `13`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если применять сортировку, то могут возникнуть проблемы с "хвостом" вектора, так как тот, как я понимаю,  должен оставаться не сортированным.

Прямолинейное решение - это решение с использованием стандартного алгоритма `std::stable_partition`, объявленного в заголовке `<algorithm>`.

Ниже приведена демонстрационная программа

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<unsigned int> v = { 9, 55, 13, 4, 6, 25, 7, 14, 7, 21, 33, 4, 12, 5, 10 };

    for ( int x : v ) std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    auto first = v.begin();
    for ( unsigned int i : { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 } )
    {
        first = std::stable_partition( first, v.end(), [&]( unsigned int x ){ return x % i == 0; } );
    }        

    for ( int x : v ) std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль

```
 9 55 13  4  6 25  7 14  7 21 33  4 12  5 10 
 4  6 14  4 12 10  9 21 33 55 25  5  7  7 13
```

Что же касается вашей программы, то циклы, подобные данному

```
for (int i = 0; i < massiv.size(); i++)
{
    if (massiv[i] % 2 == 0)
    {
        poradok.pb(massiv[i]);
        massiv.erase(massiv.begin() + i);
    }
    else if (massiv[i + 1] % 2 == 0)
    {
        poradok.pb(massiv[i + 1]);
        massiv.erase(massiv.begin() + (i + 1));
    }
}
```

являются некорректными. Во-первых, во-втором else предложении происходит выход за диапазон допустимых индексов, так как выражение `i + 1` может быть равно значению, возвращаемому функцией `size()` . Во-вторых, при удалении элемента из вектора происходит смещение всех элементов, расположенных правее удаленного элемента, влево, а потому увеличение индекса в цикле может привести к пропуску некоторых элементов. Правильная идиома удаления элементов из вектора в цикле выглядит следующим образом

```
for ( std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < massiv.size(); )
{
    if (massiv[i] % 2 == 0)
    {
        poradok.pb(massiv[i]);
        massiv.erase(massiv.begin() + i);
    }
    else
    {
        i++;
    }
}
```

Или

```
for ( auto it = massiv.begin(); it != massiv.end(); )
{
    if ( *it % 2 == 0 )
    {
        it = massiv.erase( it );
    }
    else
    {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно ввести критерий сравнения, согласно которому все числа с минимальным простым делителем до 11 сортируются в соответствии с величиной делителя, а все остальным числам приписывается некий искусственный "большой" делитель (например, `12` :) ) . Далее применяем `std::stable_sort` и получаем требуемый порядок. Если в лоб

```
    #include <cassert>  
    #include <algorithm>  
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iterator>

    unsigned min_prime_factor(unsigned v)
    {
      assert(v > 0);

      unsigned i;

      for (i = 2; i <= 11; ++i)
        if (v % i == 0)
          break;

      return i;
    }

    int main() 
    {
      unsigned array[] = { 9, 55, 13, 4, 6, 25, 7, 14, 7, 21, 33, 4, 12, 5, 10 };

      std::stable_sort(std::begin(array), std::end(array), 
        [](unsigned a, unsigned b) 
          { return min_prime_factor(a) < min_prime_factor(b); });

      std::copy(std::begin(array), std::end(array),
        std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
      std::cout << std::endl;
    }
```

Разумеется, никто вам не запрещает применить более эффективный метод поиска минимального простого делителя. И понятно что такая реализация может (и будет) заниматься поиском минимального делителя несколько раз для одного и того же значения, что в общем случае неоптимально.

Учитывая, что диапазон входных значений у вас ограничен, при необходимости не составит труда оптимизировать обработку либо путем предварительной генерации таблицы, либо (лучше?) путем [мемоизации](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) уже вычисленных факторов. Навскидку

```
unsigned min_prime_factor(unsigned v)
{
  assert(v > 0 && v <= 1000);

  static unsigned table[1001];

  if (table[v] == 0)
  {
    unsigned i;  

    for (i = 2; i <= 11; ++i)
      if (v % i == 0)
        break;

    table[v] = i;
  }

  return table[v];
}
```

Comment: жаль, что нет `stable_sort_by_key()` как в Питоне: `L.sort(key=key)`

Comment: Можно чуток ускорить (возможно лишь чисто теоретически), если делить на элементы `static unsigned p[] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11}` (в качестве ключа сортировки возвращаем индекс подходящего элемента)

Comment: @avp: Да, в ответе у @Vlad from Moscow используется привлекательный современный синтаксис с range-based for по `{ 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 }`. Но я уже решил не мельтешить с исправлениями, ибо этот момент на самом деле не принципиален.

Answer (score 0):

Навскидку (не самым эффективным способом) - что-то вроде

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned int N;
    cin >> N;
    vector<int> s(N);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        cin >> s[i];
    int m = 2;
    auto check = [&m](int n){ return n%m == 0;};
    while(s.size())
    {
        copy_if(s.begin(),s.end(),
                ostream_iterator<int>(cout," "),
                check);
        s.erase(remove_if(s.begin(),s.end(),check),s.end());
        m += 1 + (m > 2);
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

В вам просьба - не ленитесь, писать `pb` вместо `push_back` - это уже просто неуважение к языку и самому себе...

**Update**

В варианте @AnT - т.е. после 11 не проверяем на делимость, а просто выводим все подряд - достаточно изменить три строчки и добавить еще одну переменную:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int N;
    cin >> N;
    vector<int> s(N);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        cin >> s[i];
    int m[] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 1};
    int idx = 0;
    auto check = [&m,&idx](int n){ return n%m[idx] == 0;};
    while(s.size())
    {
        copy_if(s.begin(),s.end(),
                ostream_iterator<int>(cout," "),
                check);
        s.erase(remove_if(s.begin(),s.end(),check),s.end());
        ++idx;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Вот еще более короткое и эффективное решение...

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int N;
    cin >> N;
    vector<int> s(N);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        cin >> s[i];
    int m[] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 1};
    int idx = 0;
    while(s.size())
    {
        s.erase(remove_if(s.begin(),s.end(),
                          [&m,&idx](int n)
                          { return (n%m[idx]) ? false :
                              (cout << n << " ", true); }),
                          s.end());
        ++idx;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

При отсутствии поддержки C++11 - например, так (берет даже Open Watcom):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int m[] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 1};
int idx = 0;

bool pred(int n)
{
    return (n%m[idx]) ? false : (cout << n << " ", true);
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int N;
    cin >> N;
    vector<int> s(N);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        cin >> s[i];
    while(s.size())
    {
        s.erase(remove_if(s.begin(),s.end(),pred),s.end());
        ++idx;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: push_back у меня в define

Comment: также на auto check compilator ругается.

Comment: Гениально. Я снйчас заменю весь свой код фиг знает чем, и напишу, что все у меня в дефайне, а вы разбирайтесь, что такое `gh12b` - `copy`, `copy_if`, `remove_if` или `vector<int>`... Такие дефайны и есть полное неуважение к самому себе...

Comment: Значит, компилятор старый. Запишите предикат отдельным функциональным объектом, который понимает ваш компилятор...

Comment: ок ,спасибо большое

Comment: насчёт define я не согласен с вами. Я не считаю это не уважением к себе.

Comment: Посмотрите либо через полгода сами, когда свои же исходники не сможете понять, или через три дня работы в команде... Если ответ устроил - принимайте :)

Comment: Но этот вариант будет проверять делимость на `9`, а по условию этого делать не надо. Также этот вариант не останавливается на `11`, а по условию это надо сделать. Требование сохранения порядка чисел с минимальным делителем больше `11` - критическая часть условия задачи. А в этом решении она проигнорирована.

Comment: @AnT Дороже строить список простых чисел, чем проверять все. Далее, по-моему, мы по-разному воспринимаем условие. Лично я воспринимаю "и затем все остальные числа с сохранением их порядка следования относительно друг друга" как - все остальные в порядке их делимости на следующие простые числа. Впрочем, сейчас допишу ответ и для вашего варианта... Новый вариант вас устраивает? Он отвечает вашему пониманию задачи?

Comment: @Harry: Не совсем понимаю ремарку про "дороже". В условии явно пропущено упоминание `9` в качестве делителя и это явно сделано намеренно.

Comment: Потому что 9 - число составное; естественно, оно пропущено, так как число Делящееся на 9, **уже вылетает** при проверке на 3. Именно поэтому список примеров делителей - простые числа...

Comment: @Harry: Да, вы правы: проверка делимости на `9` в вашей реализации создает лишь "холостую" итерацию цикла, но не влияет на конечный результат, ибо все, что могло делиться на `9` уже ушло из массива при проверке делимости на `3`.

Comment: @Harry ,отличная реализация. Но я не знаю синтаксис языка c++11 вы можете предоставить альтернативный способ для c++ ?

Comment: См. дополненный ответ. Нужно просто заменить лямбда-функцию обычной (или соответствующим функциональным объектом).

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Спасибо тут выражается тем, что если ответ вас устраивает, пометьте его как принятый :)